# How to find the methods in Java API in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, api, mockito

I started to use Mockito, but when i call a method like when(); Eclipse didn´t show me the import class option, so, i was wondering if Eclipse have a way to search the methods in jar and know wich i can import.

I know in Delphi we can find, typing the procedure or function, and the IDE tell you the right unit to put...

So how can i do that?

Comment: i want to know if there is a shortcurt to get de corret class ou discover about the method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add Mockito and Matchers to your "Content Assist Favorites" so they'll show up even before you import the classes into your source file, as long as you've added Mockito to your project as a library.

[image: Eclipse content assist for "when"]

1. Go to `Window > Preferences` and navigate to `Java > Editor > Content Assist > Favorites`.
2. Click the "New Type..." button and add `org.mockito.Mockito`.
3. Do the same with `org.mockito.Matchers`. The Mockito class actually extends Matchers to gain access to its static methods like `any` and `eq`, but Eclipse doesn't like to show those automatically.

To test it, try typing "wh" in a new file and press Ctrl-Space. A completion for `when()` should come up; choosing it with Enter will automatically import `Mockito.when()` into your static imports.

Comment: I also suggest to set `Java > Code Style > Number of static imports needed for .*` to `0`. That way you don't need to use Content Assist the whole time for other methods.

Answer (score 2):

Just manually add `import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;` to the top of your file. Eclipse can find classes pretty easily, but I guess it doesn't search inside classes for static methods.

One way that you could get the import without having to paste it in yourself would be to type `Mockito.when`. I believe there should be an option to statically import the method.

Comment: ok, but for example, i was looking for a tutorial, and given(); and i need to import other class...

and i was wondering if Eclipse have a way to make this...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the Mockito jar is actually in your build path.

The method when() is a static method of the Mockito object. I'm not 100% sure, but I think you can't just write "when()" because Eclipse isn't going to know what you're talking about as the import stuff is based off of importing classes. So generally you do something like new ArrayList and then Eclipse knows you want ArrayList imported, but when you just type when() Eclipse doesn't know that you want to import a class with when() as a static method.

To use when in the way you want to you're going to need to do this at the top of each unit test that uses Mockito.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#when(T)